# how to insert data from one table to another and filling other columns with desired data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these four tables designed :

```
CREATE TABLE Person(
    id VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50) 
);


CREATE TABLE Coach(
    id VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    team VARCHAR(50) , 
    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES Person(id)
);

CREATE TABLE Player(
    id VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    team VARCHAR(50) , 
    age INT , 
    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES Person(id)
);

CREATE TABLE Refree(
    id VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    fifa_grade VARCHAR(50) , 
    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES Person(id)
);

CREATE TABLE Team(
    name varchar(30) PRIMARY KEY
);
```

I want to insert all persons that are not in any of refree ,coach and player   tables to **player** table and set player team to for example 'barcelona' and set the players age 30  years,i have tried code blow but it gives me syntax error:

```
insert into player (id,'chelsea',24)
select id
from person
where person.id not in (select id from coach) and person.id not in (select id from player) and person.id not in (select id from refree)
```

how can i fix this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is not correct, you can use values in the `select`:

```
INSERT INTO player (id, team, age)
SELECT id, 'barcelona', 30
from person p
left join coach c on p.id = c.id
left join player ply on p.id = ply.id
left join refree r on p.id = r.id
WHERE c.id IS NULL and ply.id IS NULL and r.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to list the columns in the `insert`:

```
insert into player (id, team, age)
    select id, 'chelsea', 24
    from person
    where person.id not in (select id from coach) and
          person.id not in (select id from player) and 
          person.id not in (select id from refree)
```